# How to create a cyclic reference with Arc and Weak?

Tags: reference, rust, smart-pointers

I have two structs:

```
struct A { 
    map: HashMap<u32, Vec<B>>,
}

struct B {
    weak: Weak<A>
}
```

When `A` is constructed, it will own several `B`, each of which links back to the `A` which was just constructed, similar to this:

```
let a = Arc::new(A { map: HashMap::new() });

let b1 = B { weak: Arc::downgrade(&a) };
let b3 = B { weak: Arc::downgrade(&a) };
let b2 = B { weak: Arc::downgrade(&a) };

a.map.insert(5, vec![b1, b2]);
a.map.insert(10, vec![b3]);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=683b6d181b3318cdeef52496cfc81a8e&version=stable&mode=debug)

This doesn't work since `Arc` does not provide a way to modify the map. [`Arc::get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.get_mut) does not work since a `Weak` is already constructed to the value.

How it is possible to construct an `A` with some `B`? I'm trying to avoid runtime checks when accessing `map` because after construction it will never be modified again. I have no problem using unsafe code or approved nightly features.

Comment: "after construction it will never be modified again" -> Does it have to be cleaned up before the end of the program? Because you *could* just leak it, and use `&'static` references instead of `Arc` and `Weak`.

Comment: @trentcl While in my specific use case this would be possible, but it's no the same to leak the value. It would be possible to modify the `Arc` or has a wrong weak-count.

Comment: Yeah, you would use `Box` instead.

Comment: @trentcl this would be a completly different scenario ;)

Comment: The only real difference is that the `Arc` can be safely dropped. But yes, this was a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Arc::get_mut()` will fail if you have even existing `Weak` references so you need to consider using *interior mutability* instead. Since you are using `Arc`, I'll assume you are in a multi-threaded environment, so I'll use a `RwLock` which is thread-safe.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak, RwLock};
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct A { 
    map: RwLock<HashMap<u32, Vec<B>>>,
}

struct B {
    weak: Weak<A>
}
```

Now you can construct these objects something like this:

```
fn init_a(a: Arc<A>) -> Arc<A> {
    let b1 = B { weak: Arc::downgrade(&a) };
    let b2 = B { weak: Arc::downgrade(&a) };
    // extra block is required so that the Mutex's write lock is dropped 
    // before we return a
    {
        let mut map = a.map.write().unwrap();
        let vec = map.entry(0).or_insert(Vec::new());
        vec.push(b1);
        vec.push(b2);
    }
    a
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Arc::new(A { map: RwLock::new(HashMap::new()) });
    a = init_a(a);
}
```

---

If you *really* want to get rid of all runtime overhead of the `Mutex`, and you don't mind using `unsafe` code, you could use an  `UnsafeCell`. It has zero overhead, but its interface requires an `unsafe` block and it's an extra layer of unwrapping in your code. Also `UnsafeCell` is not `Sync`, so you couldn't share it between threads.

To solve those problems, by making sure that you only need to consider `UnsafeCell` during construction, you can can take advantage of the fact that `UnsafeCell` has zero size cost and does not affect layout. Instead of `A`, Use a different type for constructing, which is identical to `A` apart from the `UnsafeCell`. These types can then be used interchangeably with `mem::transmute`.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::{Arc, Weak};
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
use std::mem;

struct A { 
    map: HashMap<u32, Vec<B>>,
}

struct B {
    weak: Weak<A>
}

impl A {
    fn new() -> Arc<A> {
        let a = A { map: HashMap:: new() };
        Self::init_a(Arc::new(a))
    }

    fn init_a(a: Arc<A>) -> Arc<A> {
        // Important: The layout is identical to A
        struct AConstruct {
            map: UnsafeCell<HashMap<u32, Vec<B>>>,
        }
        // Treat the object as if was an AConstruct instead
        let a: Arc<AConstruct> = unsafe { mem::transmute(a) };
        let map = unsafe { &mut *a.map.get() };
        // B's weak references are to Arc<A> not to Arc<AConstruct> 
        let weak_a: Weak<A> = unsafe { mem::transmute(Arc::downgrade(&a)) };

        // Actual initialization here
        let vec = map.entry(0).or_insert(Vec::new());
        let b1 = B { weak: weak_a.clone() };
        let b2 = B { weak: weak_a.clone() };
        vec.push(b1);
        vec.push(b2);

        // We're done. Pretend the UnsafeCells never existed
        unsafe { mem::transmute(a) }
    }
}
```

You can also do this with raw pointers, but I feel a little "safer" with `UnsafeCell`! LLVM does some optimisations when it's given guarantees that certain data is immutable, and `UnsafeCell` does some magic to protect you when it breaks those guarantees. So I'm not 100% certain of the safety of doing this:

```
fn init_a(a: Arc<A>) -> Arc<A> {
    // Raw IMMUTABLE pointer to the HashMap 
    let ptr = &a.map as *const HashMap<_, _>;
    // Unsafely coerce it to MUTABLE
    let map: &mut HashMap<_, _> = unsafe { mem::transmute(ptr) };
    let weak_a: Weak<A> = Arc::downgrade(&a);

    // Actual initialization here
    let vec = map.entry(0).or_insert(Vec::new());
    let b1 = B { weak: weak_a.clone() };
    let b2 = B { weak: weak_a.clone() };
    vec.push(b1);
    vec.push(b2);

    a
}
```

Comment: I see, that internal mutability would be a clean approach, but it feels weird to use it just for creation of the object.

Comment: @Tim Since you said you didn't mind `unsafe` code, I have added another version which removes the interior mutability after construction.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Looking forward to an answer to [Shepmasters Question on `UnsafeCell`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431702/is-it-safe-and-defined-behavior-to-transmute-between-a-t-and-an-unsafecellt) :)

Answer (score 6):

I would approach this from the opposite direction, actually.

`HashMap` is a much more complicated type than `Weak<T: Sized>`, and therefore it is much easier to swap `Weak` after the fact. Therefore, my approach would be:

1. Create the `B` with a dummy reference.
2. Create the `A`, transfer ownership of the `B`.
3. Iterate over the `B`, swapping out the `A` for the real one.

AFAIK, the standard library does not provide any way to (1) create null `Weak` and (2) atomically swap them out. Crossbeam has an example of [`ArcCell`](https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam/blob/master/src/sync/arc_cell.rs): simply search/replacing all `Arc` by `Weak` gives us a `WeakCell`!

With that `WeakCell<T>` at our disposal:

```
#[derive(Default)]
struct A { 
    map: HashMap<u32, Vec<B>>,
}

struct B {
    weak: WeakCell<A>,
}

impl A {
    pub fn new(map: HashMap<u32, Vec<B>>) -> Arc<A> {
        let a = Arc::new(A { map });
        let weak = Arc::downgrade(&a);
        for (_, bs) in &a.map {
            for b in bs {
                b.weak.set(weak.clone());
            }
        }
        a
    }
}

impl B {
    pub fn new(a: &Arc<A>) -> B { B { weak: WeakCell::new(Arc::downgrade(a)), } }
}

fn main() {
    let dummy = Arc::new(A::default());

    let (b1, b2, b3) = (B::new(&dummy), B::new(&dummy), B::new(&dummy));

    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(5, vec![b1, b2]);
    map.insert(10, vec![b3]);

    let _a = A::new(map);

    //  Do something!
}
```

Which you can see in action [on the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b4e00f0aa5ee8756eb6218f167940698&version=stable&mode=debug).

It should be possible to modify `WeakCell` to construct it from `0` (guaranteeing it would be initialized later), thus avoiding the need for the dummy reference. That's an exercise left to the reader ;)

Answer (score 4):

It's an old question, but I had similar dilemma and apparently there is a better solution than UnsafeCell if you really do not want Mutex (like me).

Since Rust 1.60 there is `Arc::new_cyclic` (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#method.new_cyclic) that takes a closure as it's parameter:

```rust
let a = Arc::new_cyclic(|weak_a| {
   let mut a = A { map: HashMap::new() };
   let b1 = B { weak: weak_a.clone() };
   let b3 = B { weak: weak_a.clone() };
   let b2 = B { weak: weak_a.clone() };

   a.map.insert(5, vec![b1, b2]);
   a.map.insert(10, vec![b3]);
   a
});
```

This solution:

- Does not require a single line of `unsafe`
- Does not use `Mutex`
- Gives you an Arc with the cycle
- And yet it does not cause memory leak because it's using `Weak`

Comment: Absolutely fantastic.  Gives them exactly what they want, with no struct changes.  I like solutions like this, because the structs don't have "implementation details" as a necessary evil of initialization.  Good to see an update of capabilities that didn't exist when this was originally asked.  I can see using this solution, _along with_ interior mutability for accessing individual parts of the parent/child classes as well, but this allows for such to not be part of the "main relationship" either, which is good.  Well done.