# Can I convert BTreeMap<&str, Cell<&str>> to BTreeMap<&str, &str> without rebuilding?

Tags: rust

Is there a way to convert a `BTreeMap<&str, Cell<&str>>` to `BTreeMap<&str, &str>` without rebuilding the entire tree?

Both trees would be binary identical, but it seems like doing `tree.into_iter().map(|(k, v)| (k, v.into_inner())).collect()` would first collect it into a Vec, sort, and then rebuild the tree.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe not.

Comment: Is this an instance where `unsafe *const` casts make sense?

Comment: Extremely relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50431702/is-it-safe-and-defined-behavior-to-transmute-between-a-t-and-an-unsafecellt

Comment: Maybe `BTreeMap` should have a `map_values` function, transforming a `BTreeMap<K, A>` into a `BTreeMap<K, B>`. I don't know how useful it would be if the `A` and `B` had different sizes, but if they have the same size, they could be mapped in-place, and then the compiler could elide the call entirely if the map function is a no-op.

Comment: What is the purpose of the conversion? Why can't you do the conversion when using the map?

Comment: I can do the conversion using `.into_iter().map().collect()`, I just don't want to rebuild the entire tree when the result will be bitwise identical.

Comment: `collect()` does not create an intermediate `Vec`, it will enumerate the key-values and build a new `BTreeMap` out of them, directly.

Comment: I mean, why can't you do the conversion when accessing the map?

Comment: @rodrigo The implementation of `FromIterator::from_iter` for `BTreeMap` does it, and that is called by `collect()`.

Comment: @PitaJ because `Cell` is only needed in the function that creates the `BTreeMap`, and I don't want to change all the code that is already using that function, not I want it to be polluted with `Cell` and related function calls when it doesn't have to be.

Comment: That's not really a great reason TBH. I suggest you just accept the inconvenience.

Comment: @lvella: Ah, I didn't know that! I assumed that the values were inserted into an empty tree, one by one. I assume somebody concluded that the ability to use `bulk_build_from_sorted_iter` was worth the intermediate `Vec`.

Comment: @PitaJ I would take readability over 5% execution time (almost) any time.

Comment: There's no safe way to achieve this, and there may not be a sound unsafe way either. Looks like you'll have to take the hit.

Comment: I was thinking a `map_values` function could be handy, but I'm not sure it could actually perform better than `.into_iter().map(...).collect()` because the bucket arrays would have a different element size, so I think it would wind up having to rebuild the whole hashtable structure anyway. It could be done without rebuilding if the bucket array elements were boxes, but then you have additional indirection in all usage just to support a rather niche optimization.

Comment: Even if we had `map_values()`, it still couldn't map in-place because for that we need to verify that order is maintained. And frankly, we don't even need `map_values()`, with specialization we can give a dedicated behavior for `map.into_iter().collect::<BTreeMap>()`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman values don't affect the order, just keys.